# vscode does not recognize terminal command ''make''

Tags: c++, makefile, terminal, sdl

I created a make file to run a sdl2 window

Make file

```
all:
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Opened a new terminal and the command ''make'' doesn't create my .exe file, it isn't really recognized at all

is there an easier way to use the cmd terminal to create an .exe file with sdl2?

I tried going the cmd path : g++ -o main main.cpp

and the result was:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So apparently the problem is that my file doesn't include SDL.h even tho it is present in the SDL folder.

Also cmd straight out deleted my ''main.cpp' file.

Also tried mingw32-make in the terminal and it also deleted my main.cpp file and found the same errors.

Comment: @john it returns 1 after failing to find SDL2 a few times and deletes my main.cpp

Comment: Yes I just realised, the command is wrong Try this `g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Comment: After `-o` you put the name you want for the executable. Your makefile command is missing that, so it thinks you want to call the executable `main.cpp`.

Comment: But if that still fails because it can't find SDL, then you have another problem.

Comment: @john thanks, this was quite a stupid and easy problem to run into, thank you very much!

Comment: Make on Windows can be installed from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).